# Default to no styling images in EE's Rich Text Editor

Tags: image, richtext, formatting

Is there a way to disable the Rich Text Editor from adding styling to images that are inserted into the field?  I am specifically referring to use of the RTE in the administration portal.

For example if I add an image it automatically has:

```
<figure style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://www.domain.com/uploads/assets/743280d7.hero2.jpg"></figure>​
```

Is there a way to have it default to just showing:

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.domain.com/uploads/assets/743280d7.hero2.jpg">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens in /system/expressionengine/rte_tools/image/rte.image.js around line 75

```
var $img = $('<figure/>')
                .css('text-align','center')
                .append(
                    $('<img alt=""/>')
                    .attr('src', image_object.thumb.replace(/_thumbs\//, ''))
                );
```

It would appear the image is being wrapped in a `<figure>` tag to allow for alignment (left, right) and to add a caption, if present, in a nested `<figcaption>` tag.

Probably only way to avoid this is to edit the script.

Comment: Sounds like a decent option as long as you dont require RTE in other areas.  I will give this a shot and report back in a bit!

Thanks

Comment: That worked great!  I changed that line to: `var $img = $('<span/>')
    .append(
     $('<img alt=""/>')
     .attr('src', image_object.thumb.replace(/_thumbs\//, ''))
    );`

Comment: Cool, glad it worked out for you.